# How to use fpdb HUD in the game

Tags: poker-tools, hud

I am trying to use [fpdb](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fpdb/index.php?title=Main_Page) to improve my understanding of the table opponents. 
I understand few displayed numbers as VPIP, hands, net profit. But are presents other numbers that I don't know how to use. Who can help me in understanding all the index presents in this HUD?

Comment: Whatever this fpdb is, don't they have some sort of documentation or entries in their FAQ about this ?

Comment: I have tried to search for a tutorial, but in vain. I have found a lot a installation/configuration tutorials, but none about how to use in the game. I guess that the statistics used in this HUD is in some way a standart for poker players, so the developers has not spent extra time in developing further documentation.

Comment: Not sure if I've heard of it? Any links you could provide in the question would be helpful.

Comment: ok, I have added a link to the project web site.

Comment: Which stats are you unsure of? If you look at the screenshots page on the link you showed it tells you what each stat is. Is your question then how to use these stats or just what they mean?

Comment: In the first line of the box displayed, are present 3 numbers. The first is vpip, the second is pfr, but the third what represents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had a quick look through the documentation for this.

I found the following information:

Default stat window layout

By default the stat windows have three rows and three columns.

VPIP    PRF     PF3

Hands   Player Name     CB_1

WTSD    Steal   Net ($)

This layout can be changed in a number of ways, but for the moment much of this all involves manually editing the config.

More information can be found [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fpdb/index.php?title=Howto_HUD)

Comment: The last doubt. PF3 I guess is the 3-bet preflop. The source page define it as PF3=Three bet preflop/3rd. How  can I relate this number with distribution of hand with which the oppo will 3-bet? PFR*PF3 ?